# Download GLOBathy TIFFs by country rather than one at a time

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, merge, wildlife-ecology, lakes

GLOBthy seems to be a very useful resource for studying lakes worldwide, however it has one significant problem; every lake is saved as  different TIFF,and apart from a few large lakes, none of them are named. However, they each have a country attached to them in the CSVs which accompany the download of the folder with the data. I have been going one at a time trying to get all the lakes in my study region, and have wasted hours with no luck. Is there any way in QGIS to automate the upload of all TIFFs whose number are asociated in the accompanying CSV with one country?

Comment: Do you have a url link to this service?

Comment: Here is the website to download the rasters: https://springernature.figshare.com/articles/dataset/GLOBathy_Bathymetry_Rasters/13404635 , there is a csv which comes with the download

Comment: I was enable to replicate your issue as I can only see a method of downloading all data at once. Is there a way to download lakes individually without downloading the entire Bathymetry_Rasters.zip?

Comment: I had the same issue as you, the structure of the GLOBathy dataset is 'somewhat' cumbersome. I didn't bother trying QGIS or any other GIS as every GIS I've used tends to be a 'duck'. Ducks can swim, walk, and fly but they're hopeless at all three. Likewise, GIS can visualise, manipulate, and store data but they're hopeless at all three. For this type of issue, I use the open source program called R. Would you be interested in my solution given that it doesn't use QGIS?

Comment: Yea a solution in R would work fine; I use R for a lot of my work, just never for GIS work (also I work on ducks....some can fly alright)